# How to decrease webpage bouncing rate?

Tags: bounce, visitors

I found some stuff on the web with tips about how to reduce bouncing rate (the percentage of web visitors which left the website without going to the any next page). Does anyone have tips which he actually tried and helped him reduce his bouncing rate ?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

1. relevant and interesting content
2. attractive design
3. good color selection
4. optimized (fast) loading

You'd be surprised how much color selection effects a visitor's desire to stay/leave.

Comment: I'd add a couple of things to this: a familiar page structure will make it easier for people to find what they want; and making the content match what users are expecting -- particularly users coming from PPC or search engines.

Comment: I'd add that you need to make sure to present the information the user initially expected. Make sure your Titles and Descriptions are on par with what the page is really about. Nothing more frustrating that clicking on a search result in a search engine and landing on page which does talk about the topic in itself, but doesn't live up to the description and title presented through the search engine result page ...

Answer (score 0):

Users do not know where to go unless you tell/show them.

In any viewable area of the site there should be a 'call to action'.  Either a 'buy now', 'signup here', etc.  This gives the user direction on where they should go next.  If you don't show them the path they won't go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise investigating any trends in the bouncing visitors - how are they arriving at the website? Assuming its via a search engine, what terms are they searching for?

If its a web page selling a product, is the pricing competitive?